# 2 questions on Page 6 of Hoffman Kunze ( Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

While studying Linear Algebra from Hoffman Kunze I have following two questions :

> **I.3. Matrices and Elementary Row Operations**
>
> One cannot fail to notice that in forming linear combinations of linear equations there is no need to continue writing the "unknowns' $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n},$ since one actually computes only with the coefficients $A_{i j}$ and the scalars $y_{i} .$ We shall now abbreviate the system (1-1) by
> $$AX=Y$$
> where
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&\cdots&A_{1n}\\\vdots&&\vdots\\A_{m1}&\cdots&A_{mn}\end{bmatrix}\\X=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\\vdots \\x_n\end{bmatrix}\text { and }Y=\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\\vdots\\y_m\end{bmatrix}$$
> We call $A$ the matrix of coefficients of the system. Strictly speaking, the rectangular array displayed above is not a matrix, but is a representation of a matrix. An $m \times n$ matrix over the field $F$ is a function $A$ from the set of pairs of integers $(i, j), 1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n,$ into the field $F$. The entries of the matrix $A$ are the scalars $A(i, j)=A_{i j},$ and quite often it is most convenient to describe the matrix by displaying its entries in a rectangular array having $m$ rows and $n$ columns, as above. Thus $X$ (above) is, or defines, an $n \times 1$ matrix and $Y$ is an $m \times 1$ matrix. For the time being, $A X=Y$ is nothing more than a shorthand notation for our system of linear equations. Later, when we have defined a multiplication for matrices, it will mean that $Y$ is the product of $A$ and $X$

Questions->

**(1)** Why in 2nd paragraph author wrote that the rectangular array displayed above is not a matrix?

**(2)** In 2nd line of 2nd paragraph author wrote the definition of matrix. How is a matrix a function from set of pair of integers into the field?
To me this definition given contradicts the definition given on Wikipedia and I can't understand it.

Definition on Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)

Can kindly anyone explain why I am confused .

Comment: The author is saying that a matrix is a function which takes a pair of integers, accesses that particular element, and returns it. The array is a representation of a matrix, but the matrix is the mapping function

Comment: for simplicity consider the 2 by 2 matrix $A$ whose entries are $a_{i,j} = i+j $, thus what author is saying is $A(i,j) = a_{i,j} = i+j$ which is just a function,  And arrangement of number we know as matrix is just a representation of it.

Comment: "❤️" is not a heart, but a symbol for heart. The numeral "1" is the number $1$, but a symbol for that number. For the same reason, a rectangular array of numbers is not a matrix, but a representation of the matrix. You may write $\pmatrix{1&2&3\\ 4&5&6}$ as `[1 2 3;4 5 6]` (as we do when using Matlab), `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}` (as we do when using Mathematica) as well. There isn't any *mathematical* reason why you must write a matrix as a rectangular array. For human communications, however, we need a convention, and the widely accepted convention is to *picture* a matrix by a rectangular array.

Comment: If it helps, this is analogous to a similar situation you may have seen in an elementary real analysis course in which sequences of real numbers are defined as functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R,$ or in a "transition to advanced mathematics" course or in a discrete mathematics course (i.e. the type of course that one might take before any proof-based mathematics course, at least in the U.S.) in which an ordered $n$-tuple is defined as a function with domain $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}.$ (Some of your previous questions have been on Lebesgue integration, so you've probably seen this.)

Comment: @user1551 How is matrix a function with range in the field? More precisely I am asking my 2 nd question ( how did your comment explains it?)

Comment: My teacher explained as "*A matrix is a phatom. Every representation is a sheet that covers the phatom*". This phatom is defined by mxn integers which, properly used, work in the field F and produces (think of function = machine that produces something) something also in the field F.

Comment: Hoffman and Kunze have already answered your question: the function is $A(i,j)=A_{ij}$. As Dave L. Renfro has pointed out in a comment above, the way we define a sequence is similar.